# Why doesn't import work for me? - Python

Tags: python, python-import

Whenever I try to import a file into python, it comes up with this error(or similar):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/My Files/username save.py", line 1, in <module>
    import keyring.py
ImportError: No module named 'keyring'
```

I am trying to create a password storing program, and I was looking up for good ways to keep passwords secure, and someone said use import keyring, so I did, except, it never works. I must be doing something wrong, but whenever I look anything up for python, it never works out for me. It's almost as if loads have things have been changed over the years.

and idea's?

Comment: I though all the modules where in the Python33 directory already? - How do would I install it?

Comment: Follow the links in my answer. Python has many modules included, but it doesn't come with *everything*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`keyring` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring) is not part of the Python standard library. You need to install it first. [Installation instructions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring#installation-instructions) are included.

Once installed, use `import keyring`, not `import keyring.py`; the latter means *import the `py` module from the `keyring` package*. Python imports should use *just* the name of the module, so not the filename with extension. Python can import code from more than just `.py` python files.

Comment: I already did `pip install keyring` + `pip list` shows that it's installed but I'm having the same error

Comment: @ShifraSec you almost certainly have multiple python installations and / or virtualenv environments, and `pip` is not installing in the same Python environment as your Python executable you are using for your script. Verify with `pip -V` (which should tell you what Python env pip installs to) or use [`python -m pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#running-pip) to preselect the right Python environment

Comment: weird I get No module named pip, I'm on MacOS btw
but it does work when I state python3
I downloaded everything using brew (including py & pip)

Edit: ok now it works and I need to run python3 not python as well..
Thanks

Comment: Then your Python version doesn’t have pip installed. It is definitely different from the other Python installation that does have pip installed. You may well be using the system Python version there. Take a look at the output of `which python`; if it is located in `/usr/bin` it’s the system Python (version 2.7) and you *don’t* want to use that one! Also informative: `python -m site`. And definitely look at `pip -V` and `which pip` for clues about your other Python environment.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyring'". And after installing this module `pip install keyring`, the same error occured with another module name. Then I came to the conclusion that it is the fact that the VSCode is not able to connect to my `venv`, even after setting the `Python Itereptor`. Press CTRL + SHIFT + P, and then type Python: Select Interceptor, and select your venv, if you want to set this.

[image]

To fix the issue, I had to force the VSCode to use the `.venv` I created, and luckily there is a dropdown to do that, on the top right corner as in the preceeding image. Click ont the Python version, and then you will be able to select your virtual environment.

[image]

Now it will take the modules from your virtual environment.